# How to Design Django models with optional fields for use with ModelForm validation?

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have some models which I want to use in ModelForm.

There are some optional values in the model. Since in my use-case, blank value does not make sense for those fields, thus I set `null=True` but not `blank=True` on those fields. I suppose that makes sense from a data model perspective.

Problem is, when you render a ModelForm, the nullable-but-not-blankable value will have `required` attribute set in the HTML form. I can unroll the form and write the fields myself - but I'd rather not (because I have to create many forms).

Now guess my options are:

- Override optional fields in ModelForm, setting `required=False`, but this is tedious (I have many optional fields), violates DRY and I don't want to do that.
- Bite the bullet and set blank=True on these models.

What's the idiomatic way to use Optional fields with a ModelForm?

Comment: `blank=True` is about making fields optional, it has nothing to do with a blank value. `blank=True` has no implications on the model level, only on `ModelForm`s derived from it.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? it the optional field shown to the screen on not. if shown, what's the issue with blank=True, if not just don't add the field in model form.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem thanks I am stupid. I looked at documentation for ModelField, and blank=True does exactly what I need.